# Has this framework been abandoned or what?

Tags: w2ui

Latest activity on this framework was on July 21, 2014. There hasn't been any news or updates about this framework. The community isn't active at all. Have the developers stopped and abandoned this framework or is there something else going on? I really like how clean and modern looking this framework is. But if it's abandoned I don't see why would I use this.

Comment: The website has a github link which shows recent activity. That would have been a better place to start than asking a non-programming question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

He emailed me:

> I think it would be better to evaluate activity by github commits:
>   https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/commits/master. Currently, I am
>   working on releasing 1.5 version, which should be out soon.

Answer (score 0):

There is an email listed at the bottom of this support page:

http://w2ui.com/web/support

Suggest you send an email and ask.

Comment: This is really more of a comment.

Comment: Apologies. As you can see by my history I am not here often. Happy for moderator to move to a comment.